# Mysql query getting complicated - need to wrap another SELECT around a multiple query statement

Tags: mysql

I am doing this query which works and first inserts multiple records based on the SELECT statement and after that it updates the table with an UPDATE.

```
INSERT table_name (field1, field2)
SELECT 103, field_x FROM another_table WHERE field_y != "";
UPDATE table_name SET field3 = CONCAT('103', '-', id)
```

I now need to add another SELECT statement where the result of that executes the whole lot above multiple times. Sort of like below, but of course that won't work. I could do this in PHP, but it would be good to get the lot in one query.

```
SELECT xxx FROM third_table (
    INSERT table_name (field1, field2)
    SELECT xxx, field_x FROM another_table WHERE field_y != "";
    UPDATE table_name SET field3 = CONCAT('xxx', '-', id)
)
```

I've tried putting the SELECT at the bottom again, but I can't get it all to work together. Running the top two queries together is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in PHP, by running multiple statements.

Use a [transaction](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) to ensure that the changes take place as a group.

You are trying to use syntax that simply doesn't exist in the SQL language.  You can't put an INSERT or UPDATE in a subquery.  You can't use multiple statements in a subquery separated by semicolons.  You can't open parentheses for a subquery in a random location as you are doing.

You are just blindly making up syntax and semantics and hoping it will work.  This is never the right way to do programming.

Comment: Or pehaps he could use a stored procedure ?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani, he can use a stored procedure, but that offers no guarantee of atomicity.  It's a completely independent decision to use a stored procedure.

Comment: I was not implying that using a stored procedure he would automatically gain atomicity. I meant it as an alternative to using PHP. Putting the statements inside a transaction remains the key point, though.

Comment: Right, transactions are the important part.  The OP said "I can do this in PHP" and I assumed this would be an easier path than to introduce another layer of stored procs that offer no value in this case.